# How to change COM port name in device manager while inserting external device

Tags: usb, conversion

Serial to USB converter connect to com port in computer.
In "device manager" show the com port name and (number).
At the same time, In "Devices and printers" show the device name.

I want to change the com port name in "Device manager".
And at the same time, change the device name in "devices and printers".

I have attached images for your references.
[image]
please give steps on how to change.

Comment: What is it that you want to change? “USB Serial Port”? Or “COM16”?

Comment: I want to change "USB Serial Port" in device manager.

Comment: "USB Serial Port" only i want to change. Give an any idea....

Answer (score 1):

Devices and Printer is a separate structure. Changes in Device Manager do not automatically carry over. Windows has been like this for a long time

Comment: please give steps on change com port name in "Device manager".

Comment: Insert external device to comport in computer. please give steps on change com port name in "Device manager". I already tried to FTDI website (FT prog tool). but can't change com port name.

Answer (score 0):

Naren, don't know if you still need to find out how to do this, but here is how I have done it:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Browse to the COM Port or device you're interested in changing
3. Right click the device and select "Properties"
4. Select the "Details" tab
5. In the "Property" box, select "Container ID"
6. Copy the "Value" presented
7. Open the Registry editor
   a. MUST now back up the registry in case you boff something and need a road home.
8. Select the "Edit" menu once your registry is loaded
9. Select "Find"
   a. insert the copied value into the "Find What?" box.
   b. select the "Find Next" button.
   c. You may have to select "Find Next" several times until you find the registry
   entry you're looking for. You'll know you have the correct registry entry
   when you come across one that contains the REG_SZ value Name of "Friendly
   Name."
10. Double-click the "Friendly Name" icon. This will open an editable box for you
    to change the name of the item.  In my case, when I change the friendly name
    of a COM port I only change the name and not the COM port number. This does have
    the potential to get gummed up if you aren't careful with what you do.
11. After you make your change, exit the registry editor and reboot.
12. Open the Device Manager and you should see that device's friendly name changed
    to what you desired.
    Hope this helps...